# To determine whether given series is convergent or not.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Series with $n^{th} $term is given as$\left(\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}\right)^{n^{2}\log n}$.I apply root test but I am facing problem in evaluating $n^{th}$ root of $a(n)$.Please give me some start for calculating that limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with the reciprocal
is easier.

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}\right)^{n^{2}\log n}
&=\left(\frac{\log(n)+\log(1+1/n)}{\log n}\right)^{n^{2}\log n}\\
&=\left(1+\frac{\log(1+1/n)}{\log n}\right)^{n^{2}\log n}\\
&=\left(1+\frac{1/n+O(1/n^2)}{\log n}\right)^{n^{2}\log n}\\
&=\left(1+\frac{1+O(1/n)}{n\log n}\right)^{n^{2}\log n}\\
&=\left(\left(1+\frac{1+O(1/n)}{n\log n}\right)^{n\log n}\right)^{n}\\
&\approx e^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

The original is
about $e^{-n}$
which goes to zero.

Note:
Wolfy says that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} e^n \left(\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}\right)^{n^{2}\log n}
=\sqrt{e}
$.

Comment: I don't get how to use that last note to calculate limit

Comment: @omkarGirkar Fix $\epsilon>0$ then by the above limit it follows that for $m$ large enough, for all $n\geq m$:
$$e^n\left(\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)}\right)^{n^2\log(n)} < \sqrt{e}+\epsilon$$
so
$$\left(\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)}\right)^{n^2\log(n)} < (\sqrt{e}+\epsilon)e^{-n} $$
then
$$ \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)}\right)^{n^2\log(n)}
< (\sqrt{e}+\epsilon) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  e^{-n}
= (\sqrt{e}+\epsilon) \frac{1}{1+e^{-1}} < \infty$$

Comment: @martycohen..as we were finding nth root of $a(n)$..power should be just $n logn$..no matter it will be $1/e$..and series will be convergent.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is a good idea to check whether the limit of the $n$th term as $n$ tends to $\infty$ is zero. For this, we take the log of the $n$th term and get 
$$ n^2 \log n \log \left( \frac{\log n }{ \log (n+1) } \right) = n^2 \log n \left( \log \log n - \log \log (n+1) \right) = n^2 \log n \log \log n - n^2 \log n \log \log (n+1),  $$
which is an $\infty - \infty$ form.

If this limit as $n \to \infty$ is other than $-\infty$, then of course your series does not converge.